# Playing local video file on AppleTV

Tags: swift, xcode, tvos, apple-tv

I am looping a simple slide show on an AppleTV.  I am able to stream the video file just fine and it plays great, but when I move the file locally (bundled), it fails to play on the actual AppleTV. However, it plays fine on the simulator.

Swift 4.1
Xcode 9.3
AppleTV 4th gen with tvOS 11.3

Here is my code:

```
guard let fileURL = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "showroom", ofType:"m4v") else {
        debugPrint("video not found")
        return
    }

    playerAsset = AVAsset (url: URL(fileURLWithPath: fileURL))
    playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: playerAsset!)   //(url: fileURL as URL)
    queuePlayer = AVQueuePlayer(items: [playerItem!])
    playerLooper = AVPlayerLooper(player: queuePlayer!, templateItem: playerItem!)


    // Create a new AVPlayerViewController and pass it a reference to the player.
    let controller = AVPlayerViewController()
    controller.player = queuePlayer

    // Modally present the player and call the player's play() method when complete.
    present(controller, animated: true) {
        queuePlayer!.play()
    }
```

When I run on the device, I receive the following console messages and just a blank screen with a spinner on the AppleTV:

```
2018-04-03 09:13:00.225001-0500 ShowRoom[231:10709] [UIDevice.battery] No internal battery found

2018-04-03 09:13:00.404092-0500 ShowRoom[231:10709] [AXM-MediaDesc] Did observe change on. path:'currentItem' object:<AVQueuePlayer: 0x1c0027420> change:{
kind = 1;
new = "<AVPlayerItem: 0x1c40049f0, asset = <AVURLAsset: 0x1c4420c20, URL = file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/D6FD828D-2109-4946-BCAE-4080A0114912/ShowRoom.app/showroom.m4v>>";


2018-04-03 09:13:00.469734-0500 ShowRoom[231:10709] [AXM-MediaDesc] Did observe change on. path:'currentItem' object:<AVQueuePlayer: 0x1c0027420> change:{
kind = 1;
notificationIsPrior = 1;
old = "<AVPlayerItem: 0x1c40049f0, asset = <AVURLAsset: 0x1c4420c20, URL = file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/D6FD828D-2109-4946-BCAE-4080A0114912/ShowRoom.app/showroom.m4v>>";

2018-04-03 09:13:00.470929-0500 ShowRoom[231:10709] [AXM-MediaDesc] Did observe change on. path:'currentItem' object:<AVQueuePlayer: 0x1c0027420> change:{
kind = 1;
new = "<AVPlayerItem: 0x1c40053c0, asset = <AVURLAsset: 0x1c4420c20, URL = file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/D6FD828D-2109-4946-BCAE-4080A0114912/ShowRoom.app/showroom.m4v>>";
old = "<AVPlayerItem: 0x1c40049f0, asset = <AVURLAsset: 0x1c4420c20, URL = file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/D6FD828D-2109-4946-BCAE-4080A0114912/ShowRoom.app/showroom.m4v>>";

2018-04-03 09:13:00.543119-0500 ShowRoom[231:10709] [AXM-MediaDesc] Will stop processing legibility events for player item: (null)
```

Any ideas on what I'm missing here? I've also tried a .MOV file with the same results. Thanks!

Comment: It’s been days since I posted this and not one comment.   I’m really surprised no one has seen this before.

Comment: I also had this error, but not only local source. HLS sources can throw it too. I see a message between your console messages that 'did observe change on'. Maybe you can try to remove observe after every loop finished as fallows playerItem.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath:"status");